# Unexpected Cache Request Header and 304 status

Tags: c#, http, iis, https, authorization

I have a WPF window with a WebBrowser control.  I want to navigate to a page that requires Authentication, but I want to automatically login the user.

```
byte[] authData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UserName + ":" + Password);
_header = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authData);
Browser.Navigate(url, string.Empty, null, _header);
```

The problem is that even though I'm providing the Authorization header, the WebBrowser still prompts for username and password.  I enter the username and password from my code into the prompt and I am authenticated (so I don't have any typos).

The site is running in IIS with Basic Authentication and https.

After watching the traffic in fiddler the first request I see has a 304 status code and the Authorization header is present.  This request is followed by a second request that returns the 401 status code.  For this request there is no Authorization header.

***Anyone know where the cache headers below are coming from?  I'm not adding them and I think they are causing the problem.***

First Request Headers from Fiddler

> **Cache** If-Modified-Since: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 19:52:22 GMT If-None-Match: 
>   "527fa775d61ce1:0"
>
> **Client** Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E;
>   AskTbORJ/5.15.23.36191; MDDRJS)
>
> **Cookies/Login** Authorization: Basic T25saW5lSGVscFVzZXI6SG93Q2FuSUhlbHBZb3Uh
>
> **Transport** Connection: Keep-Alive Host: docs.newcenturysoftware.com

Second Request Headers from Fiddler

> **Client**  Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0;
>   Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET
>   CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C;
>   .NET4.0E; AskTbORJ/5.15.23.36191; MDDRJS)
>
> **Miscellaneous** Referer: https://docs.newcenturysoftware.com/
>
> **Transport** Connection: Keep-Alive Host: docs.newcenturysoftware.com

Let me know if you need any other info.  Thanks.

**EDIT**
If this expected behavior for a redirect as mentioned in the comments below, perhaps a better question is why is the redirect happening in the first place?  Is there a setting we can change in IIS to prevent the redirect?

The first request is to https://docs.newcenturysoftware.com/
The second request is to https://docs.newcenturysoftware.com/welcome.png (just the default iis image).

NOTE - I don't get the redirect when I browse to the page in IE or Chrome.

**EDIT 2 with "fix"**

Since the redirect is expected because of a firewall redirection and the removed authorization header also seems to be expected on a redirect, I fixed my code by listening to the Browser.Navigated event and resending the request again with the header information.

```
void BrowserNavigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //Handle the dropped authorization header for the first request (because of firewall redirect) 
        //and resend the request with the authorization again.
        _docWindow.Browser.Navigate(e.Uri, string.Empty, null, _header);
        _docWindow.Browser.Navigated -= BrowserNavigated;
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be a security precaution. See my question about the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092259/http-should-authorization-be-kept-when-redirection-is-handled

Comment: It looks like the redirect is happening because of the firewall redirection.  And like @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp mentions in his post, the Authorization header is expected to be removed when redirected based on most of the posts I have found.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2011/03/31/how-to-lose-your-authorization-head-er-with-a-bad-url.aspx

Comment: I fixed it in my code my listening to the Browser.Navigated event and resending the request again with the header information.

        void BrowserNavigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //Handle the dropped authorization header for the first request (because of firewall redirect) 
            //and resend the request with the authorization again.
                _docWindow.Browser.Navigate(e.Uri, string.Empty, null, _header);
                _docWindow.Browser.Navigated -= BrowserNavigated;
        }